# Keep getting errors on a basic c# console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I've trying to learn c# but keep coming across a problem. Essentially, I'm trying to learn how to create a class that does some function and is called to perform that function by the application.

the error I have ended up with (there have been loads of others but I've tried to play around to 'fix' them) is

`is a 'type' but is used like a variable`

the code I've put together so far is;

```
    namespace FirstConsoleApplication
    {

        class Program
        {
            public class checkConvertValue
            {
                public string formula1(string x)
                {
                    Int32 isnumber = 0;
                    bool canConvert = Int32.TryParse(x, out isnumber);
                    string returnValue;
                    if (canConvert == true)
                    {
                        int val3 = Int32.Parse(x);
                        switch (val3)
                        {
                            case 50:
                                returnValue = "yep its 50";
                                break;
                            case 51:
                                returnValue = "hmmm.... its 51... what are you gonna do about that??";
                                break;
                            case 52:
                                returnValue = "lets not get sloppy now...";
                                break;
                            default:
                                returnValue = "nope, its definately something else";
                                break;
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnValue = "Thats not a number";
                    };
                        return returnValue;
                }
            }
           static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string num;
                string result1;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess what the value is, hint... its integer and between 1 and 100");

                    num = Console.ReadLine();
                    result1 = checkConvertValue(num);
                    Console.WriteLine(result1);

                } while (result1 != "yep its 50");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

}
```

can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Ramhound that error message has nothing specifically to do with braces (`{` / `}`); and (now you've edited it), no - it has nothing to do with the `switch` statement.

Comment: @MarcGravell - I will take your word on it but the **error** I see is within the switch statement. The `Main` method also appears to be outside of the class.  I also see one to many `}` but as you said that particular fact is not causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the function by class name, which is wrong. You have to do like this

```
result1 = new checkConvertValue().formula1(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You presumably mean:

```
result1 = new checkConvertValue().formula1(num);
```

or if you make it (`formula1`) a `static` method:

```
result1 = checkConvertValue.formula1(num);
```

btw; there's no point in parsing `x` twice; if the `TryParse` succeeds, the integer value is stored in `isnumber`.

Comment: YES! that's done it! ok so my problem was that I needed to effectively route to the function via the class and that the reference to the class needs to end with "()".

Comment: Thanks for the additional point, I'd missed that. I've been trying to layer additional complexity

Comment: @Nav to clarify that explanation: `formula1` is an *instance* method; to access that method you need an instance reference, which is what the `new checkConvertValue()` provides; after that we must indeed tell the compiler what *method group* we want to access - `formula1`. `static` methods do *not* require an instance - and are suitable for things like utility methods that do not depend on per-instance state

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the *class* checkConvertValue as if it were a method.
To actually call the method you need to call the *formula1* method from an instance of class *checkConvert* value.
Try this:

```
num = Console.ReadLine();
checkConvertValue classReference = new checkConvertValue();
result1 = classReference.formula1(num);
Console.WriteLine(result1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here.

- `checkConvertValue` doesn't contain a constructor which takes num (assuming its a string), i think you meant to call `formula(...)`
- You need to create an instance of `checkConvertValue` and then call the `formula` method from that or make the class and method static and call it like `checkConvertValue.formula1` etc...

Answer (score 0):

object `checkConvertValue` is a class but you are using it as a method.

you need to declare an instance of it before you can use the method `formula1`

```
num = Console.ReadLine();
checkConvertValue chkVal = new checkConvertValue();
result1 = checkConvertValue.formula1(num);
Console.WriteLine(result1);
```

Comment: Thanks, just for my knowledge going forward, does it make any difference to use 
<code> 
checkConvertValue chkVal = new checkConvertValue();
result1 = checkConvertValue.formula1(num);
</code>

compared to 
<code>
result1 = new checkConvertValue().formula1(num);
</code>